# DHCP server changing IP of my laptop frequently(every few seconds)

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dhcp

I am using latitude 3570 with ubuntu 16.04 on my college network. It has Realtek gigabit ethernet card model RTL8168. Driver r8169. My IP address assigned by DHCP is changing every few seconds. Other systems with ubuntu 14.04 and 12.04 in the network are working fine. Setting static IP is not allowed. Is it a problem with DHCP server or my system. If my system has the problem then is it NIC or ubuntu 16.04 itself?

Comment: DHCP IP addresses have a maximum lease time, check that you get the correct one (syslog, if necessary run dhcp client manually). Another possible reason is that the connection is flakey and it reconnects frequently, getting a new address each time. Again, check logs. In the case, might be a driver problem.

Comment: A client must request an address. A server cannot just send a new one. Try a different Ethernet cable. If cable is unplugged and replugged, the client should request an IP again. 90% of problems are cables.